# "Identifier not declared" in Verilog. Anyone know why I'm getting this?

Tags: verilog

Been working for a while on figuring this problem out, but brief searches produced nothing and Verilog syntax guides don't seem to provide any useful information.
I am compiling these two Verilog files together along with another that consists solely of the pre-made gates (ANDs, ORs, NANDs, NORs and NOT) used.

```
// 2-to-4 Decoder implemented in structural verilog style.
module decoder_2_to_4 (B, A, G, Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3);
input B;
input A;
input G;
output Y0;
output Y1;
output Y2;
output Y3;
wire NOTB;
wire NOTA;

    // Structural verilog style.
NOT u1 (B,NOTB);
NOT u2 (A,NOTA);
AND3 u3 (NOTB,NOTA,G,Y0);
AND3 u4 (NOTB,A,G,Y1);
AND3 u5 (B,NOTA,G,Y2);
AND3 u6 (B,A,G,Y3);

endmodule
```

---

```
`timescale 1 ns / 100 ps

module test_fixture;
reg done;
//  reg [1:0] test_input;   //2 input
reg [2:0] test_input;   //3 input
wire f0, f1, f2, f3;        //Put output wires here

initial
begin
   $dumpfile("decoders.vcd"); // save waveforms in this file
   $dumpvars;                 // saves all waveforms

   // initialize done signal to 0
   done = 1'b0;
/*
//2 Input Test
   // test 00 case
   test_input[1] = 0;
   test_input[0] = 0;

   // wait 5 ns, then test 001 case
   #5 
   test_input[1] = 0;
   test_input[0] = 1;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 010 case
   #5
   test_input[1] = 1;
   test_input[0] = 0;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 011 case
   #5
   test_input[1] = 1;
   test_input[0] = 1;

   // Bogus kluge to extend simulation time for better viewing.
   #5 done = 1'b1;

   $finish;       // finished with simulation
end
*/
// 3 input test

   // test 000 case
   test_input[2] = 0;
   test_input[1] = 0;
   test_input[0] = 0;

   // wait 5 ns, then test 001 case
   #5 
   test_input[2] = 0;
   test_input[1] = 0;
   test_input[0] = 1;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 010 case
   #5
   test_input[2] = 0;
   test_input[1] = 1;
   test_input[0] = 0;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 011 case
   #5
   test_input[2] = 0;
   test_input[1] = 1;
   test_input[0] = 1;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 100 case
   #5
   test_input[2] = 1;
   test_input[1] = 0;
   test_input[0] = 0;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 101 case
   #5
   test_input[2] = 1;
   test_input[1] = 0;
   test_input[0] = 1;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 110 case
   #5
   test_input[2] = 1;
   test_input[1] = 1;
   test_input[0] = 0;

   // wait another 5 ns, then test 111 case
   #5
   test_input[2] = 1;
   test_input[1] = 1;
   test_input[0] = 1;


// Instantiate circuit
decoder_2_to_4 u0 (test_input[2], test_input[1], test_input[0], f0, f1, f2, f3);
end
endmodule   // test_fixture
```

---

The problem is that when I compile I receive the following errors:

```
Identifier (decoder_2_to_4) not declared
"test.v", 94:

syntax error
"test.v', 94: decoder_2_to_4 u0<-
```

Does anyone have a clue why I am getting this? I really have no idea what is going on, and a nudge in the right direction would certainly help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: To further confirm the compilation error, the prebuilt_gates file (the one not listed) and Decoders.v (the file containing the 2-to-4 Decoder implementation) both compile together just fine without test.v (the second file posted and the one that is noted by the errors.)
Problem is definitely in there somewhere.

Comment: You probably need to indicate the command you used to compile these files to get any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit should not be instantiate inside the `initial` block.

```
// Instantiate circuit
decoder_2_to_4 u0 (test_input[2], test_input[1], test_input[0], f0, f1, f2, f3);
end
endmodule   // test_fixture
```

should be:

```
end
// Instantiate circuit
decoder_2_to_4 u0 (test_input[2], test_input[1], test_input[0], f0, f1, f2, f3);
endmodule   // test_fixture
```

---

`module`s can only be instantiated inside other `module`s or `generated`-blocks (and `generate`-blocks can only be instantiated inside modules). It is illegal to instantiate module in any other manner such as inside a `initial`-block or `always`-block.

Instantiating a `module` inside an `initial`, `always`, `task`, or `function` will attempt to treat the `module` as an variable, of which non exists and give an error.

The actual rule itself is spreed out in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) *Annex A*. Look for all the places `module_instantiation` is used within Annex A.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked immediately; what is the reason for this error? It's obviously some principle of basic Verilog syntax I overlooked. Also, bonus points for speed. I really appreciate it.